# Replace Dynamic Values In text

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, architecture, system-design

I Am Implementing a SQL Alarm system that monitors some of our Data.

This Alarm system basically calls a Stored Procedure which triggers the alarm  based on the Output error code returned.

**Example:**

@ErrorCode = -100 ==> **Trigger Alarm**

@ErrorCode = 0 ==> **Do nothing**

now when the alarm is triggerd it goes for the database and fetches **users** and the **message** that should be sent to them.

---

The message to be sent contains some data that should be fetched from the database based on the stored procedure that triggered that alarm.
ex:

***Message1** :

Dear User

The Content for **%ServiceName%**  will end in **%NbrOfDays%** Days.*

***Message2** :

Dear User

The Number of subscribers for today are **%NbrOFSubscribers%***

---

As you can see the the data required is dynamic for each message and depends on the stored procedure that triggers the alarm.

what Should be used to get the  data from the stored procedure and replace them with the dynamic values in the message ( %ServiceName%, %NbrOfDays%, %NbrOFSubscribers%)

One of my thoughts was to return them as an XML output parameter.
as the below and replace them.

```
<ServiceName> Great Stories </ServiceName>
<NbrOfDays> 10 </NbrOfDays>
<NbrOFSubscribers> 200 </NbrOFSubscribers>
```

Comment: Your stored procedure could create a temporary table with a column for the Key and a column for the Value. In Key put your substitution string (IE %XXX%) and in value the actual text. Then return the temporary table and do the replacement in code.